# select max(number) and where timestamp>yesterday mixes up the results/rows

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, max, where-clause

I have a simple table:

| id | temperature | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 23 | 1630770051 |
| 18 | 24 | 1630772051 |
| 4799 | 35 | 1632140689 |

I want max(temperature) from today or yesterday

Example 1)

```
SELECT max(temperature), DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
FROM `zimmer_raumdaten`
group by DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp));
```

max(temperatur) DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
26.70   4
26.60   5
23.90   6
44.10   7
28.00   8
35.30   9
37.80   10
31.60   11
36.70   12
36.60   13
38.30   14
26.90   15
27.10   16
46.00   17
47.90   18
23.00   19
25.00   20

Result looks good.

But when I`m trying to fetch only one result for example for today - the result mixes up the rows.

```
SELECT max(temperature), DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), id
FROM `zimmer_raumdaten`
where DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = DAY(NOW());
```

| max(temperatur) | DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25.00 | 20 | 4977 |

The id is not correct - the row 4977 has temperature 19.00.

I appreciate every kind of ideas/thoughts on the SQL Statement.

cheers

Comment: Your second query is malformed and can only run in MySQL prior to version 5.7.5: the problem is that `MAX()` cannot be used in the absence of a `GROUP BY` when there are other non-aggregated columns.

Comment: Can you reproduce the case in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ? It may be an issue with the version of MySQL you are using. I tried in MySQL 8 and it works as expected. See example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8gjAozA9ga1HmBFV4zVjss/0

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Under that extension's rule, your second query is equivalent to using [ANY_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) on your `id` column. That means MySQL is free to choose any row to fulfill that value.

```sql
SELECT max(temperature), DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), 
       ANY_VALUE(id)     /* <-   bad. bad. bad. */
FROM `zimmer_raumdaten`
where DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = DAY(NOW());
```

If you want to find the `id` of the row containing the highest temperature for the day in question, you need a subquery.

```
               SELECT MAX(temperature) temperature,
                      DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))) day
                 FROM zimmer_raumdaten
                GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)))
```

Then you incorporate that query into a main query to recover the detail row from your table matching that temperature.

```
SELECT a.temperature, 
       b.day,
       a.id
  FROM zimmer_raumdaten a
  JOIN (
               SELECT MAX(temperature) temperature,
                      DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))) day
                 FROM zimmer_raumdaten
                GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)))
       ) b  ON a.temperature = b.temperature
           AND DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.timestamp)) = b.day
 WHERE b.day = DAY(NOW())
```